# IsNull() isn't returning all values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have this table

```
TABLE (Name varchar, Value varchar, Active bit)
```

And data

```
'Name1', '1', NULL
'Name2', '1', NULL
'Name3', '1', 1
'Name4', '1', NULL
'Name3', '2', NULL
```

This script I'm trying to run, but it only returns 1 row.

```
Select Name,Value FROM Table WHERE Active = IsNull(1,Active)
```

Shouldn't it be returning all the `NULL` and `1` rows in the table? Why does this not work as expected?

Comment: Try this `Select Name,Value,IsNull(1,Active),IsNull(Active,1) FROM Table` to know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
WHERE Active IS NULL OR Active = 1
```

`ISNULL()` function is used to replace `NULL` value into your desired value.

The expression `ISNULL(1, Active)` will always return `1` since `1` is not null. The documentation on `ISNULL()`

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value. 
>   Syntax 
>   **ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )**

So I *think* this is the expression you want to build:

```
WHERE ISNULL(Active, 1) = 1
```

Comment: Sure you can do it like this, but my question is more about `IsNull()` itself, and why it's not working like your answer?

Comment: maybe you're confused on how to use `ISNULL()`. try this `WHERE ISNULL(Active, 1) = 1`

Comment: Ok now it makes sense.

Comment: The SQL in question actually returns all rows with non-null Active column.

Answer (score 1):

ISNULL will use second param if first param is NULL
Here first param is 1 which is not NULL , so it evaluates to 1
So only rows with value 1 will match